# Send an e-mail from an exchange server with powershell

Tags: powershell, email

Is it possible to send an e-mail from an exchange server trough powershell? I need to send a message every morning when a certain event happens while checking a sql database.

Best regards,
Thijs

Comment: It is. Have a look at `Send-MailMessage` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, all you need is SMTP server name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-6

Further, you can schedule the powershell script, daily in task scheduler.
https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/